# Yocto - glib-gettextize: not found

Tags: yocto, glib, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to compile a recipe based on autotools, but it still fails in do_configure:

```
glib-gettextize: not found
```

However, I have glib-2.0 in my `DEPENDS` which generates the `glib-2.0-dev` package containing the binary. In `glib.inc` file :

```
[...]    
    FILES_${PN}-dev += "[...]
                            ${bindir}/glib-gettextize \
[...]
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency on `glib-2.0` does give you access to glib-2.0-dev, but it's the glib-2.0-dev compiled for target architecture. This means the binaries typically won't be compatible with your build host so the bindir isn't even added to path -- it usually wouldn't make sense (glib-gettextize happens to be a shell script so might actually work but other tools would not).

You should add `glib-2.0-native` to your DEPENDS as well: this ensures that glib-2.0 gets compiled for your build host and the binaries are made available for your configure.